# Word-break, if hyphened

Tags: html, css

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/RwRbmNR)

I'm trying to avoid word-breaks, in my `.threadTitle`, by using `display: inline-block`. This works, however when adding a *hyphen* inbetween two letters will it will cause a break anyways.

---

[image]

---

Neither `word-break: keep-all` nor `display: inline-block` has the desired effect.

```
  .threadTitle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: keep-all;  
    flex: 1 1 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent text wrapping:

```css
.threadTitle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="threadTitle">Thread-Titleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't find this property online, I was rather searching for `word-break`, I will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a Unicode problem, not an HTML one. You need to use non-breaking hyphens (`‑`, U+2011) instead of a normal hyphens:

```html
<p>This-is-a-really-long-sentence-separated-by-breaking-hyphens-that-will-be-split-among-various-lines.</p>
<p>This&#8209;is&#8209;a&#8209;really&#8209;long&#8209;sentence&#8209;separated&#8209;by&#8209;non&#8209;breaking&#8209;hyphens&#8209;that&#8209;won't&#8209;be&#8209;split&#8209;among&#8209;various&#8209;lines.</p>
```

This is useful for making sure hyphenated words are never broken between two lines.

---

If you don't want wrapping *at all*, use `white-space: nowrap;`, as [Ori Drori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64232217/9253414) suggests.

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a really long sentence separated by breaking (normal) spaces that won't be split among various lines because <code>white-space: nowrap;</code> is being used.</p>
```

Comment: Upvoted. I guess this is a really well solution, however `white-space: nowrap;` saves me from formatting it each time.